# running a couple of SQL statement with 1 click

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a very simple app that has only a button. When the user clicks the button, it runs a 5-6 SQL statements. But it gives errors like below. IF I run the sql on SQL Management Studio, it runs without a problem. But if I run it with c#, it gives errors.

How can I solve this?

[image]

here is my sql code. I put "GO" between each statement.

```
        CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AGIRLIK]
    @DONEMREF int
    AS
    DECLARE
    @LOGICALREF  INT,
    @EXPCENTERREF  INT,
    @POSTEDPRDREF INT,
    @OVHDCLNREF INT,
    @TOTAL FLOAT
    DECLARE C_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
    SELECT D.LOGICALREF,D.POSTEDPRDREF  ,D.EXPCENTERREF ,D.OVHDCLNREF  ,SUM(OT.TOTAL)
    FROM LG_001_ACTOVRHDDIST  D 
    INNER JOIN LG_001_OVHDTRANS as ot 
    ON D.OVHDCLNREF=OT.OVHDCLNREF 
    WHERE D.POSTEDPRDREF=@DONEMREF
    GROUP BY D.LOGICALREF,D.POSTEDPRDREF  ,D.EXPCENTERREF ,D.OVHDCLNREF
    OPEN C_CURSOR
       FETCH NEXT FROM C_CURSOR
    INTO @LOGICALREF ,@POSTEDPRDREF ,@EXPCENTERREF ,@OVHDCLNREF,@TOTAL
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
      BEGIN
                UPDATE LG_001_ACTOVRHDDIST
                SET TOTAL=@TOTAL
                WHERE POSTEDPRDREF=@DONEMREF
                AND POSTEDPRDREF=@POSTEDPRDREF
                AND EXPCENTERREF=@EXPCENTERREF 
                AND OVHDCLNREF=@OVHDCLNREF

    FETCH NEXT FROM C_CURSOR
    INTO  @LOGICALREF ,@POSTEDPRDREF ,@EXPCENTERREF ,@OVHDCLNREF,@TOTAL
    END
    CLOSE C_CURSOR
    DEALLOCATE C_CURSOR


    GO 

    ALTER VIEW LS_AGIRLIK_DAGILIM
    AS
    SELECT LOGICALREF [REF],
    FICHENO [URETIM_EMRI_NO],
    DATE_ [URETIM_EMRI_TARIHI],
    (SELECT CODE FROM LG_001_ROUTING WHERE P.ROUTINGREF=LOGICALREF) [ROTA_KODU],
    (SELECT NAME FROM LG_001_ROUTING WHERE P.ROUTINGREF=LOGICALREF) [ROTA_ADI],
    (SELECT CODE FROM LG_001_ITEMS WHERE P.ITEMREF=LOGICALREF) [STOK_KODU],
    (SELECT NAME FROM LG_001_ITEMS WHERE P.ITEMREF=LOGICALREF) [STOK_ADI],
    CAST ((SELECT WEIGHT  FROM LG_001_ITMUNITA where ITEMREF=P.ITEMREF) AS FLOAT) [GR_MT],
    (CAST ((SELECT WEIGHT  FROM LG_001_ITMUNITA where ITEMREF=P.ITEMREF) AS FLOAT))*ACTAMOUNT [AGIRLIK],

    ACTAMOUNT [GERCEKLESEN_MIKTAR],
    (CASE STATUS 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'BASLAMADI'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'DEVAM_EDIYOR'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'TAMAMLANDI'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'KAPANDI'
    END)
    [DURUMU],
    ACTMATERIALCOST [GERCEKLESEN_MALZEME_MALIYETI],
    ACTOVERHCOST [GERCEKLESEN_GENEL_GIDER_PAYI],
    ACTTOTALCOST [GERCEKLESEN_TOPLAM_MALIYET] 

    FROM LG_001_PRODORD P WHERE CANCELLED=0 AND STATUS<>0 AND 
    ROUTINGREF NOT IN (SELECT LOGICALREF FROM LG_001_ROUTING WHERE CODE LIKE 'B%')
    AND SPECODE<>'MONTAJ'
    AND DATE_ BETWEEN '2014-02-06' AND '2014-02-13'

    GO 
    ----------------------------

    ALTER VIEW DBO.[LS_CARPAN]
    AS
    SELECT 
    REF,
    AGIRLIK/(SELECT SUM(AGIRLIK) FROM LS_AGIRLIK_DAGILIM) [YUZDE]
    FROM LS_AGIRLIK_DAGILIM

    GO 
    ----------------------------
```

Comment: `GO` is a batch separator understood by Management Studio and `sqlcmd` not a TSQL command. You would need to use that as a delimiter between batches in your C# code too.

Comment: I understand, but what should I use?

Comment: what error are you facing?

Comment: I dont think it is duplicate.I am not asking how to use GO. I am asking what should I replace GO with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string sPath = @"D:\script.sql";
if (File.Exists(sPath) == false)
    return;
string sServer = "SQL SERVER INSTANCE NAME";
string sUserID = "sa";
string sPassword = "password"; 

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;                        
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "sqlcmd";
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

if (sPassword == "")
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-S {0} -i {1} ", sServer, sPath);
else
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-S {0} -U {1} -P {2} -i " + Convert.ToChar(34) + "{3}" + Convert.ToChar(34), sServer, sUserID, sPassword, sPath);

bool started = p.Start();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

p.WaitForExit();
```

USE [databasename]
must be specified at the first line of the script.

Comment: Does assume that `sqlcmd` is installed on the client of course.